# Transferring "getframe" movie from MATLAB to Powerpoint

Tags: matlab, powerpoint, movie

I am using "getframe" in a for loop to create a movie in MATLAB. I want to play the clip in Powerpoint presentation. I'm not sure what is the best way to save and transfer the movie to Powerpoint. I've tried "movie2avi":

```
movie2avi(F, 'mymovie.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

However, when I play it back in Windows Media Player, I basically get noisy green and pink horizontal lines. 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you play the avi in a video player?

Comment: The first input argument is the movie object, not the filename.

Comment: Use `VideoWriter` instead. Do not use `movie2avi`. That is deprecated: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html